# Verify the number of copies that have prints

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I have a table that when printed generates a record in a txt telling the user who printed it, on which machine, which printer, what was the document and when. But I would like to also record the number of copies, but I have no idea how.

Code that takes information from the computer:

```
Declare Function GetComputerName& Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lbbuffer As String, nSize As Long)
Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
Declare Function WNetGetUser Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetUserA" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpUserName As String, lpnLength As Long) As Long

Function deMAQUINA() As String
Dim Buffer As String * 256
Dim BuffLen As Long
Dim lngX As Long
Dim strCompName As String
BuffLen = 255
If GetComputerName(Buffer, BuffLen) Then deMAQUINA = Left(Buffer, BuffLen)
End Function

Function deUSUARIO() As String
Dim Buffer As String * 256
Dim BuffLen As Long
BuffLen = 256
If GetUserName(Buffer, BuffLen) Then deUSUARIO = Left(Buffer, BuffLen - 1)
End Function
```

Code that registers:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim vUsuario As String, vMaquina As String
    vUsuario = deUSUARIO()
    vMaquina = deMAQUINA()

    Open "\\Caminho\do\arquivo.txt" For Append As #2

        Print #2, "O usuário: " & vUsuario & " | pela Máquina: " & vMaquina & " | pela impressora: " & ActivePrinter & " | Imprimiu o documento " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "| no dia: " & Now

    Close #2

    Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OBSOLETO\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 8) & ".txt" For Append As #3

        Print #3, "O usuário: " & vUsuario & " | pela Máquina: " & vMaquina & " | pela impressora: " & ActivePrinter & " | Imprimiu o documento " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "| no dia: " & Now

    Close #3

End Sub
```

If anyone knows, could please help?

I'm sorry, I had to translate, why no one knew how to respond on server BR

Comment: How are the users printing? Are you calling the PrintOut Method?

Comment: No, Common printing (Crtl + P)